# Find Biggest Concatenation Word in List

Tags: c#, arrays, concatenation

I have some code that doesn't work as expected. As output, I get:

`Concatenation.Concatenation+ConcatWord`

I have no idea how to make it work as I would like. It should output the biggest concatenation word in the array and the number of its characters. The input might be:

```
string[] words = {"five","fivetwo","fourfive","fourfivetwo","one","onefiveone","two","twofivefourone"}`
```

for which the output should be:

```
"fourfivetwo" with 11 characters
```

[Here's my code](http://www.filedropper.com/concatenation_1)

I think something is wrong with this part, but I'm not sure.:

```
List<ConcatWord> concatWords = new List<ConcatWord>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    ConcatWord concatWord = new ConcatWord(i, data[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i != j)
        {
            if (data[i].Contains(data[j]) && data[i].Length > data[j].Length)
            {
                concatWord.words.Add(data[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not understand the question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide an example that reproduces the problem along with the desired output.

Comment: Can you share the input, and expected output of your program?

Comment: This code is not easy to understand. I would break it apart into separate methods so each method does one thing.

Comment: What is `ConcatWord`?

Comment: @Jon Kittell, Ok, I add another code with some commentary, `ConcatWord` is my List of expected bigger concatenation word from array of words.

Comment: Without knowing about `ConcatWord` you're question is unanswerable. If the expected output of your input is `"forfivetwo" with 11 characters`, then why?

Comment: The OP has included it as a link

Comment: @jdphenix, In `In ConcatWord` class i check and add words from my data array, then if i find repeated word i remove them from list. Expected output need to be only word wich contains from other words from this array. In my input this was `fourfivetwo` wich contains `fourfive` and `two` from my array.

Comment: @AydinAdn Maybe so, but I'm behind a corporate firewall right now so... there's a reason why SO questions need everything to answer the question *in the question*

Comment: @jdphenix, I can add full listing of my programm if it help.

Comment: @Vaik You need to isolate the parts that do not behave as you expect, not the whole program. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] words = { "five", "fivetwo", "fourfive", "fourfivetwo", "one", "onefiveone", "two", "twofivefourone" };

var allCombinations = words.SelectMany(w => words, (left, right) => left + right);
var combinedWords = words.Where(w => allCombinations.Contains(w));
string longestCombinedWord = combinedWords.OrderByDescending(w => w.Length).First();

Console.WriteLine(longestCombinedWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can make it shorter

```
string[] data = { "five","fivetwo","fivetwo","fivetwo","fourfive","fourfivetwo","one","onefiveone","two","twofivefourone" };

string longestWord = data.OrderByDescending(words => words.Length)
                         .Distinct()
                         .First();

Console.WriteLine (longestWord);
```

Comment: Yes, this longest word, but this not concatenation word, what include other words from array...

Comment: @Vaik do you mean removing duplicates? Check my updated answer... `Distinct()` will remove the duplicates

Comment: need to be something like `fourfivetwo` its not biggest word in array but this word include `fourfive` and `two` from this array using concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You could break it apart.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var searchTerms = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
            var words = new List<string>
            {
                "five",
                "fivetwo",
                "fourfive",
                "fourfivetwo",
                "one",
                "onefiveone",
                "two",
                "twofivefourone"
            };

            var wordsAndMatches = new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                {"five", 0}, {"fivetwo", 0}, {"fourfive", 0},
                { "fourfivetwo", 0}, {"one", 0}, {"onefiveone", 0},
                {"two", 0}, {"twofivefourone", 0}
            };

            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                var numberOfMatches = GetNumberOfOccurances(word, searchTerms);
                wordsAndMatches[word] = numberOfMatches;
            }

            foreach (var wordsAndMatch in wordsAndMatches)
            {
                var result = string.Format("{0} contains {1} number of matches.", wordsAndMatch.Key, wordsAndMatch.Value);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            var highestNumberOfConcatenations = wordsAndMatches.Values.OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
            var wordWithHighestNumberOfMatches = wordsAndMatches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == highestNumberOfConcatenations);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has the highest number of matches at {1} matches.", wordWithHighestNumberOfMatches.Key, wordWithHighestNumberOfMatches.Value);
        }

        private static int GetNumberOfOccurances(string word, IEnumerable<string> searchTerms)
        {
            return searchTerms.Count(word.Contains);
        }
    }
```